# View redirect not happening

Tags: ajax, redirect, view, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view where data is displayed in table (View 1). What I want is , when I click on button in table row then it should move to another view (view2) and data from table row to be displayed in new view(view2) input boxes.  I am doing ajax post from view 1 to controller of view 2 . I received parameters as well in controller of view 2 and it executes successfully but it is not redirecting the view.

```
  public IActionResult BillingHome(QueuePatient queuePatient)
    {
        ....//Parameters are visible here
        return View("BillingHome",billingHomeViewModel);
   }
```

But this view 2 is not visible. Application stays in View 1. What could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue and it is because using ajax request to send row data to controller will make the `return View(model)` from the controller becomes the ajax received the **html content** in the response.

Like screenshot below. I have a get request in the screenshot, but it's the same to use a post request.

[image]

So the best solution is using form submit like the [asp.net core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). But the tutorial is passing an id to controller and using Id to query database and bind to a model then return View. We can also write code like this to avoid querying database.

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#1").click(function(){
            $(location).attr('href', "https://localhost:7037/home/edit?Id=1&Title=movie1&Price=12.5");
        });
    </script>
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Movie mov)
{
    return View(mov);
}
```

Test result:

[image]